# generate a list from list elements

Tags: r, list, apply

I have the following list `L1`

```
$`A`
[1] 101 201

$B
[1] 90 91
```

I would like to generate a list (with a general number of elements) that has a row for each element of `L1` containing a sequence of one before the element, the element itself and one after, something like this:

```
$`A`
[[1]] 100 101 102
[[2]] 200 201 202

$B
[[1]] 89 90 91
[[2]] 90 91 92
```

I have tried different combinations of `lapply` plus the line `function(x) c(seq(x-1), seq(x+1))`, but noting seems to give me an output like the above.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
L1 <- list(A = c(101, 201),
           B = c(90, 91))

#nested lapply loops
lapply(L1, lapply, function(x) x + -1:1)
```

Comment: or short `lapply(L, lapply, '+', -1:1)`